# How do I get Assetic to stop running filters if the file hasn’t changed?

Tags: php, zend-framework2, assetic

I'm using Zend Framework 2, and I'm using the following function with my Abstract controller to group all assets from the modules, then write/minify them to a cache file, and then serve file path to be written to the page via a view helper.

```
protected function prepareAssets() {

    // Prepare FilterManager with all filters that will be used
    $FilterManager = new FilterManager();
    $FilterManager->set('scss', new ScssphpFilter());
    $FilterManager->set('cssmin', new MinifyCssFilter());
    $FilterManager->set('jsmin', new JSMinFilter());

    $AssetManager = new AssetManager();
    // Prepare the AssetManager with all core assets
    $AssetManager->set('coreCss', new AssetCollection(array(
        new FileAsset('public/vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css'),
        new FileAsset('public/vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css'),
        new FileAsset('module/application/assets/css/fonts.css'),
        new FileAsset('module/application/assets/css/main.scss'),
    )));
    $AssetManager->set('coreJs', new AssetCollection(array(
        new FileAsset('public/vendor/modernizr/modernizr-2.6.2.js'),
        new FileAsset('public/vendor/respond/respond.min.js'),
        new FileAsset('public/vendor/jquery/jquery-1.9.1.min.js'),
        new FileAsset('public/vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js'),           
    )));

    // Add the controller specific assets
    $controllerCss = new AssetCollection();
    foreach ($this->assets['css'] as $file) {
        $controllerCss->add(new FileAsset($file));
    }
    $AssetManager->set('controllerCss', $controllerCss);
    $controllerJs = new AssetCollection();
    foreach ($this->assets['js'] as $file) {
        $controllerJs->add(new FileAsset($file));
    }
    $AssetManager->set('controllerJs', $controllerJs);

    // Setup factory to create the assets with cachebusting
    $factory = new AssetFactory('public/cache');
    $factory->setAssetManager($AssetManager);
    $factory->setFilterManager($FilterManager);
    //$factory->setDebug(true);
    $factory->addWorker(new CacheBustingWorker(CacheBustingWorker::STRATEGY_CONTENT));

    // Create the assets
    $coreCss = $factory->createAsset(array(
        '@coreCss',         
    ), array(
        'scss',
        '?cssmin',                  
    ));

    $controllerCss = $factory->createAsset(array(
        '@controllerCss',           
    ), array(
        'scss',
        '?cssmin',
    ));

    $coreJs = $factory->createAsset(array(
        '@coreJs',
    ), array(
        '?jsmin',
    ));

    $controllerJs = $factory->createAsset(array(
        '@controllerJs',            
    ), array(
        '?jsmin'
    ));

    // Write the assets to cache
    $writer = new AssetWriter('public/cache');
    $writer->writeAsset($coreCss);
    $writer->writeAsset($controllerCss);
    $writer->writeAsset($coreJs);
    $writer->writeAsset($controllerJs);

    // rename files with proper extensions to be served correctly
    $coreCssPath = $coreCss->getTargetPath(); rename(getcwd().'/public/cache/'.$coreCssPath, getcwd().'/public/cache/'.$coreCssPath.'.css');
    $controllerCssPath = $controllerCss->getTargetPath(); rename(getcwd().'/public/cache/'.$controllerCssPath, getcwd().'/public/cache/'.$controllerCssPath.'.css');
    $coreJsPath = $coreJs->getTargetPath(); rename(getcwd().'/public/cache/'.$coreJsPath, getcwd().'/public/cache/'.$coreJsPath.'.js');
    $controllerJsPath = $controllerJs->getTargetPath(); rename(getcwd().'/public/cache/'.$controllerJsPath, getcwd().'/public/cache/'.$controllerJsPath.'.js');

    // add paths to view model
    $view = $e->getParam('application')->getMvcEvent()->getViewModel();
    $view->coreCssPath = $coreCssPath.'.css';
    $view->controllerCssPath = $controllerCssPath.'.css';
    $view->coreJsPath = $coreJsPath.'.js';
    $view->controllerJsPath = $controllerJsPath.'.js';

}
```

However when running, every page load takes several seconds, regardless of if the original files have changed, which tells me that it's processing the files through the filter everytime, although the cache file itself is not being updated.

Am I using the CacheBustingWorker wrong, or am I missing something else?